# A part of an activity displaying listview in android

Tags: android-listview

I want to display the list view in half of the screen and the other half contains some static content. When i tried to put the listview, the whole screen is repeated in the loop. I want only that particular part the screen in listview. Can anyone help?

This is my MainActivity.java

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();        

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("text", menu[i]);
        hm.put("icon", Integer.toString(image[i]) );            
        aList.add(hm);        
    }

    String[] from = { "icon","text" };

    int[] to = { R.id.icon,R.id.text};        

   SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.activity_test_main, from, to);

    ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

This my activity_test_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/new_background"
>
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/katrina" />
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Katrina"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="katrina@gmail.com"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/single_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Or how exactly are you doing it? What does your layout look like?

Comment: My layout has an image at the top and below that image i want to display some items in listview. Now I'm getting the listview along with the top image

Comment: Only the relative layout should display the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm getting this right you want to display the `ListView` below the arrow `ImageView`?

You can simply put the `ListView` below the `ImageView` inside the `RelativeLayout`, then set the `android:layout_below` param to the id of the `ImageView`...`arrow` and finally make sure your `ListView`'s id is set to `list`

Comment: ya I'm getting somewhat. Half screen remains static and half screen shows the list view again with the static content.

Comment: Is there any way to change the simple adapter to display only the list view using R.id.list instead of R.layout.activity_test_main?